# Asp.NET C# Image not Upload

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am new to Asp.Net
i try to save image in a directory and the information in a data base, the information is saved successfully but the image is not saved in the directory.

My image upload code:

```
  protected void Post_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();


            if(Image.HasFile)
            {                
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(Image.PostedFile.FileName);
                string filesize = Image.FileBytes.Length.ToString();
                string filepath = "../Posts/"+filename;
                Image.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Posts/" + filename));
                string qry1 = "insert into Images(Image_Name,Image_Size,Image_Path)values('" + filename + "','"+filesize+"','"+filepath+"')";
                SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(qry1, con);
                cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            string qry = "insert into Post(Post_Title,Post_Description,Post_Category,Post_Tag,Post_Date)values('" + Post_title.Text+ "','" + Description.Text + "','" + Category.Text + "','" + Tag.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry,con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I don't believe you can use `..` in the map path call, you are probably throwing an exception.

Comment: @RonBeyer I think you can as long as it does not go outside of root (which OP did - should be failing in that case).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yes,  probably true.  Also the OP should know that the code is vulnerable to an attack with a creatively uploaded file name

Comment: @GrantWinney very true

Comment: @GrantWinney good point - probably saved by `Image.HasFile` which probably is false...

Comment: @RonBeyer `Server.MapPath(".")` returns the current physical directory of the file (e.g. aspx) being executed `Server.MapPath("..")` returns the parent directory

Comment: @SteveWellens I understand what it does, but if you try to use `../` from the root directory, it will throw an exception because you are trying to access a directory outside of your application. Probably not what is going on in this case, but not inaccurate.

Comment: @RonBeyer - The user didn't say anything about an exception. Using `..` is relative to the active _page_ not the application directory.  My best guess it the file is being saved _somewhere_ on the drive but he is looking in the wrong place.